# Error while linking Jenkins with Testlink : Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: jenkins, testlink

I am trying to trigger a job from jenkins which will build and link to testlink for executing test cases.
I have configured Jenkins with Testlink parameters

URL: http://10.204.222.216:8012/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
Dev Key: a75272894aa2e86a576bace7a5ce4fea(generated via testlink)

I have also configured jenkins job with valid parameters like testproject, testplan etc

testlink version: 1.9.15

Jenkins version: 2.7.3

Using Xampp 3.2.2 for hosting Apache(testlink),mysql and Tomcat(jenkins)

```
<b>Here is the error log</b>
<b>****************************************************************************************</b>
Preparing TestLink client API.
Using TestLink URL: http://10.204.222.216:8012/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php

FATAL: Error verifying developer key: Failed to parse server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog.
br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException: Error verifying developer key: Failed to parse server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:64)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.<init>(TestLinkAPI.java:146)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:331)
    at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:206)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse server's response: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:188)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.BaseService.executeXmlRpcCall(BaseService.java:90)
    at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.MiscService.checkDevKey(MiscService.java:61)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:186)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: Error communicating with TestLink. Check your TestLink configuration.
Sending e-mails to: kabeer.hr@aricent.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: I found some answers related to the problem and most of them are saying, the problem is related to BOM, or any other charecter at the begining of the server response. How do I check the server response? I am triggering the build from chrome browser, so where should I look for the server response file(xml) so that i can make sure there is no BOM. I have made sure that encoding is set to UTF-8. please help